# Update value in another table based on ID reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called `Jobs` & `Tags`. In the Jobs table I have a column called TagID. I want this to be an ID that references TagID in the Tags table.

*Jobs*

```
|Id, CompanyName, Title, Link, TagId, PublishedDate, Country, City, Description|
```

*Tags*

```
|Id, TagId, Tag|
```

Basically I want `Jobs.TagId` to reference `Tags.TagId` and when an entry in `Jobs` is modified I want an entry in `Tags` to respect that change (i.e. if an entry in `Jobs` is deleted, all entries with that jobs TagId in Tags should also be deleted).

What I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    TagID int NOT NULL,
    Tag varchar(255) NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CompanyName varchar(255), 
    Title varchar(255), 
    Link varchar(255), 
    TagID int UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TagID FOREIGN KEY (Tags) REFERENCES Tags(TagID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PublishedDate DateTime,
    Country varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    Description varchar(MAX)
)
```

Example structure I want to achieve:

Jobs

```
|Id, CompanyName, Title,           Link, TagId, PublishedDate, Country, City,     Description|
|1,  Apple,       Senior Engineer, link, 12,    2019-12-13,    USA,     Michigan, Fun Job    |
```

Tags

```
|Id, TagId, Tag        |
|1,  12,     C++       |
|2,  12,     C#        |
|3,  12,     Javascript|
```

Now, if Jobs.Id 1 is deleted, all the entries in Tags with the TagId 12 should be deleted. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Right now I get:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Tags' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_TagID'.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Move the foreign key to the Tags table.

Comment: @GMB "Update value in another table based on ID reference" and "How can I achieve this behaviour?"

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` should work just like that.

Comment: @jarlh Hmm, I get `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Tags' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_TagID'.` I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired behaviour, all I really had to do was to move the query to the other table.

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CompanyName varchar(255), 
    Title varchar(255), 
    Link varchar(255), 
    TagID int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PublishedDate DateTime,
    Country varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    Description varchar(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE Tags(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    TagID int,
    Tag varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_TagID FOREIGN KEY (TagID)
    REFERENCES Jobs(TagID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Now If I have these entries:

Jobs

```
|Id, CompanyName, Title,           Link, TagId, PublishedDate, Country, City,     Description|
|1,  Apple,       Senior Engineer, link, 12,    2019-12-13,    USA,     Michigan, Fun Job    |
```

Tags

```
|Id, TagId, Tag        |
|1,  12,     C++       |
|2,  12,     C#        |
|3,  12,     Javascript|
```

If I delete `Jobs.Id = 1` all the entries in `Tags.TagID = 12` will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it.

From [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

```
CREATE TABLE Tags(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    TagID int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Tag varchar(255) NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CompanyName varchar(255), 
    Title varchar(255), 
    Link varchar(255), 
    TagID int UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TagID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tags(TagID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PublishedDate DateTime,
    Country varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    Description varchar(MAX)
)
```

Comment: Hmm, That kind of defeats the whole purpose of what I'm trying to do. But I hear you.

Comment: Then that's not possible from my ind. You should use the relation without having key relationship or you should alter your `Tags` schema to store the data.